# Monitoring EKS Kubernetes LoadBalancer service Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, prometheus, amazon-eks

I have created few services in Kubernetes with type: LoadBalancer.

Platform: EKS.

Is there a way to get number of 4xx or 5xx errors from this LoadBalancer? I have tried the following:

Prometheus - Does not seem to be any metric collected for services with HTTP response codes.

AWS Cloudwatch - Does not show data points for the 2xx, 3xx, 4xx or 5xx errors. Shows other metrics like latency, request counts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

in CloudWatch docs ELB metrics show 4xx and 5xx errors:

```
HTTPCode_Backend_2XX
HTTPCode_Backend_3XX
HTTPCode_Backend_4XX
HTTPCode_Backend_5XX
```

From EKS environment you could get the ELB id/name (e.g. with `kubectl get svc SERVICE_NAME -o yaml`), and use that to extract the metrics from CloudWatch. It's a bit of a convoluted process, but logically could work.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html#loadbalancing-metrics-clb